# exports variable didn't change after operate by required

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, commonjs

I store variables in config.js, and I import those variables to different function with different file.
Then I import those functions and variables to main app.js.
The issue is when I exports as obj, values " **could be changed** " after call those functions
But I exports as variables directly, values " **couldn't be changed** " after call those functions

how can I exports variables directly ??

Here is an example below

```
//config.js
exports.varNum = 100;
exports.varBoolen = false;
exports.obj = {
    name:"Kai",
    age:31,
    single:true
};
```

```
// funcA.js
let { varNum, obj } = require("./config")

module.exports = function add (){
    varNum += 1;
    obj.age += 1;
}
```

```
//funcB.js
let { varBoolen, obj } = require("./config")

module.exports = function change (){
    varBoolen = !varBoolen;
    obj.single = !obj.single;
}
```

```
//app.js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
let { varNum, varBoolen, obj } = require("./config")
let add=require("./funcA")
let change=require("./funcB")

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ status: "ok", data: { varNum, varBoolen, obj } })
})
app.get("/add", (req, res) => {
    add();
    res.json({ status: "add" })
})
app.get("/change", (req, res) => {
    change();
    res.json({ status: "change" })
})
```

Comment: You cannot export variables directly. Export an object and change its properties.

Comment: Well destructuring creates a **local variable**, and your functions change those local variables not the property of the module exports objects.

Comment: Thank you all !!  
@Bergi  destructuring creates a **local variable** I totally forgot this. But another question , why I exports obj and destructuring . It' works by this method, I can get altered value in other file.

Comment: It's still the same object stored in the local variable and the `exports.obj` property, and you can mutate that object. Destructuring doesn't do deep copies.

Comment: @Bergi Oh!!! I got it thank you!!